# I could not understand why l+=[i] and l=l+[i] gives a difference while passing value through reference

Tags: python-3.x

l=[](this is list)

'''
def add(a,i):a+=l[i]
'''

add(l,3)

print(l)  >>>it works,gives output [3].
but,

'''
def add(a,i):a=a+[i]
'''

add(l,3)

print(l)  >>>doesn't work,gives output [0],why?

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://repl.it/repls/AcceptableUpsetNotification#main.py). Also consider putting code into code blocks that start with triple backticks like these: `\`\`\``. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/26793721).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second, it is defining a new local value `l` instead of writing to the global `l`, leaving the global `l` the same. The first does work because it isn't setting a value, which would by default be local for the function.

You could change the second to this to work properly, although using `global` is generally considered bad practice.

```
def add(l, a):
    global l

    l = l + a
```